# Not able to generate required data structure using asn1 compiler

Tags: asn.1

I am converting NGAP asn1c to c data structure , i am able to compile all the file successfully , it generating .c and .h files but , it containing nested structure ,when i grep that nested structure that structure are are not present. i am using asn1c-0.9.29 version . and asn1 file's given in NGAP spec 138 413.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you need to use `asn1c` from the [mouse07410's fork](https://github.com/mouse07410/asn1c) as it has support for Aligned PER encoding and better support for `Information Object Class` and `Information Objet Set` definitions.

See also https://github.com/mouse07410/asn1c/issues/44

Comment: As you suggested I used mouse07410 fork for PER generation but still substructure are absent and ProtocolIE-Field is not having structures. Whie compiling it am getting this kind of WARNING:
 Parameterized type maxProtocolIEs expected for maxProtocolIEs at line 6711 in NGAP_V4.asn
WARNING: Parameterized type NGAP-PROTOCOL-IES expected for NGAP-PROTOCOL-IES at line 6720 in NGAP_V4.asn
WARNING: Parameterized type NGAP-PROTOCOL-IES expected for NGAP-PROTOCOL-IES at line 6722 in NGAP_V4.asn

Comment: You could safely ignore these warnings. You are probably still using the asn1c from the vlm's repository. See https://github.com/mouse07410/asn1c/issues/44